# Change netbeans color

Tags: netbeans, fonts

I am trying to setup netbeans 7.3 on Ubuntu 12.04. My problem is that both the color of the font in the project window and the background are white. I can only see something when I choose it/click on it. 
How can I change either the font color or background colr in netbeans 7.3?
Thanks!

Comment: have you found any solution so far? I have the same problem

Comment: no, nothing. Just reinstalling a different version:(

Comment: which version did you install?

Answer (score 3):

Open your netbeans,

Tools->options

Select 'Fonts&colors ' tab,Then you can change the colour

Comment: thanks for the answer :-) This changes the color of the window containing the code. I am searching for a way to change Fonts&Colors in the project window.

Answer (score 0):

We are seeing some problems with fonts on Ubuntu. Suspect it is a JDK issue. See https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=221778, which doesn't sound exactly the same as yours. Could you file a bug on NB? Could you file a bug in NB bug DB?

Comment: I will do so. Actually I had this problem quite on a few installations in UBUNTU

Answer (score 0):

Netbeans does not use GTK themes correctly.  Changing the background color of the project window (and any other window besides the editor) has been an ongoing issue for over a decade.  Some people mention changing the look and feel with --laf but that means you have to create a custom look and feel just to change the background color which is probably more time consuming that just modifying the Netbeans source code and hacking the colors yourself.

There are several issues open for this.  They get created from time to time over the years but  they get closed with out anyone actually fixing the issue.

Comment: He's complaining about white text on white background.  So the text is invisible.  I hope that's not the default :)

Answer (score 0):

You can change the "LookAndFeels" by opening the IDE with a suffix
(go to the netbeans-7.3.1 directory)

./bin/netbeans --laf Metal

or you change the settings in ./etc/netbeans.conf
Here you add " --laf javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalLookAndFeel" to "netbeans_default_options"

More about the LookAndFeels: http://wiki.netbeans.org/NBLookAndFeels